# PythonとSeleniumを使ってのスクレイピング。リンクが全てJavaScriptになっている予約システムのリンクをたどりたい。

Tags: javascript, python3, web-scraping, selenium-webdriver

使用システム： macOS Big Sur、Python 3.12.1、Seleinum 4.16.0

https://www.city.katsushika.lg.jp/tourism/1002753/1030217/1003234.html

から予約システム；

https://rsv.shisetsu.city.katsushika.lg.jp/katsushika/web/rsvWGetCounterAction.do

に移ると（０７：００からしかアクセスできない）、リンクが以下のような記述になっています；

```
<a href="JavaScript:startMode(1);"><em>施設を利用するにはこちらをクリックして下さい。</em></a>
```

リンクをたどりたくて、ChromeのwebdriverとSeleniumのメソッドを使って、例えば、

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, system_xpath)
element.click()
```

とすると、ターミナル上で何かしら実行されてしまい、目的のリンク先のページが表示されません。
さらにこのリンクをクリックして表示されるページ内のリンクも同様にJavaScriptを実行するようになっています。

どうすればリンク先ページをSeleniumを使って（または他のモジュールを使って）表示できるのか教えてください。

1週間くらいハマってしまい、抜け出せません！　よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: PyAutoGUI等のRPAソフトを組み合わせてみてはどうでしょう？ [MacでSelenum+PyautoGUIを使ってZoomに自動出席](https://qiita.com/LemniscaterN/items/d137d8b0a0bb7b8af7c5), [MacでのPyAutoGUIの注意点](https://qiita.com/LemniscaterN/items/103019bbfeab36c9fab4), [私たちの使っているPyAutoGUIは遅い、遅すぎる](https://withcation.com/2022/04/17/faster-pyautogui), [【テスト自動化】Selenium /MacOSでの導入（Python、VSC導入、パス設定、Safariドライバ設定）](https://susakiworks.com/selenium_macos_setup/), [\[サンプルあり\] Pyautogui/SeleniumでCSVダウンロード！システム連携で使えるRPAプログラミング](https://www.glic.co.jp/article/89)

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。しかし、画面のスクリーンショットを撮ったりしたいわけではないのです。ページをたどっていった先にカレンダが表示されるます。そこに施設の空き状況が表示されるので、空いているところの予約を取りたいのです。

Comment: 紹介記事から読み取ったのはスクリーンショットを取ることでしょうが、PyAutoGUIは人がマウス/キーボードを操作しているようにシミュレートすることですので、Webサイトがどういう仕組みになっているかにかかわらず人が目で見て操作出来ることはだいだい再現出来るはずです。サイトがすべてJavaScriptで出来ていようが関係無くできるでしょうし、人の操作に従って表示される画面に対してどう入力したりすれば良いか等は直感的に扱えるのではありませんか？ [【Python】PyAutoGUIとは?できることや使い方を解説](https://one-div.com/programming/python/what-is-pyautogui)

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。今回のプログラムではPyAutoGUIは使う予定はありません。しかし、便利なモジュールを教えてくださり、ありがとうございます。勉強して、一度別件で使ってみます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> どうすればリンク先ページをSeleniumを使って（または他のモジュールを使って）表示できるのか

以下のコードは `Python 3.11.6/Selenium 4.18.1/chromedriver 123.0.6312.58` で実行しています。

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'ja_JP'})
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

url = 'https://www.city.katsushika.lg.jp/tourism/1002753/1030217/1003234.html'
driver.get(url)

elm = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a:has(wel[data-txt="葛飾区公共施設予約システム"])')
elm.click()

# open new window
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

# 予約システム
elm = wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(., "施設を利用するにはこちらをクリック")]'))).click()

# 予約申込み
elm = wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a:has(img[alt="予約の申込み"])'))).click()
```

#### 追記

> execute_script() を使った場合のリストを再度表示してくださいませんか？

###### `a` 要素の `href` 属性から抽出

```py
from urllib.parse import unquote

# 予約システム
elm = wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(., "施設を利用するにはこちらをクリック")]')))
driver.execute_script(elm.get_attribute('href'))

# 予約申込み
elm = wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a:has(img[alt="予約の申込み"])')))
driver.execute_script(unquote(elm.get_attribute('href')))
```

###### HTML ソースから JavaScript コードをコピー&ペースト

```py
# open new window
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(., "施設を利用するにはこちらをクリック")]')))
driver.execute_script('return startMode(1);')

# 予約申込み
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a:has(img[alt="予約の申込み"])')))
driver.execute_script("""
    return sendActionClassName(((_dom == 3) ? document.layers['disp'].document.formwtarnsloginaction : document.formwtarnsloginaction),
           gRsvWTransLoginAction, 'TransInstSrchVacantAction');
""")
```

Comment: 回答どうもありがとうございます。早速コードを実行させて、動作することが確認できました。`--use-agent`も与えないと表示されないことが私の書いているコードと同じで、驚きましたよ。ともあれ、長い間の懸案が解決して、プログラムの開発を進める糸口をつかめました！これを機会に今後もよろしくお願いいたしますm(__)m。ところで、回答くださったコードの最後のセミコロンは不要ですよね？

Comment: 今気がつきましたけれども、`a:has(wel[data-txt=葛飾区公共施設予約システム`のところは閉じカッコ（　`]`　と　`)`　）は不要なんですか？試しにカッコをつけて動作させたところ、同様に実行されました。

Comment: 、この先のページに進むのにもJavaScriptが使われていて、「予約の申込み」というボタンは `<a href="javaScript:sendActionClassName(((_dom == 3) ? document.layers['disp'].document.formwtarnsloginaction : document.formwtarnsloginaction ), gRsvWTransLoginAction, 'TransInstSrchVacantAction');"><img src="image/bw_rsvapply.gif" border="0" alt="予約の申込み"></a>` というリンクになっています。単純にご教授いただいたコードをコピペして、 `driver.execute_script` の引数をこのスクリプトコードにしたら、ターミナルで `SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?` と表示されました。恐れ入りますが、これについてもリンク先のページの表示の仕方をご教授願えませんか？ここのシステムは全て同様にリンクがJavaScriptで構成されています。参考資料をご提示くだされば、自分で調べます。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ごめんなさい、回答を作成する段階で書き損じをしてしまいました。修正します。

Comment: 「予約の申込み」部分を追加しました。JavaScript のコードをコピーするのも手間なので、この部分については少し考えてみます。

Comment: 早速対応くださりありがとうございます。今後勉強したいので、今回の件のような問題について、どういうこと、例えば、JavaScript など、学ぶべきこともあわせてご指導くださるとありがたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ‘return JavaScriptの関数など’ でスクリプトの実行結果を返すんですね！これはリンクのコードも理解する必要がありますか？それと、’driver.execute_script’の使い方も勉強する必要ありますか？お忙しいところ、いろいろと質問して、すみません。

Comment: `href`属性の JavaScript コードを直接実行する様に書き換えました。`%20` などの URL encode された文字列を戻すために `urllib.parse.unquote()` を使用しています。

Comment: 今回の場合は、`href` 属性に書かれている JavaScript のコードを `driver.execute_script()` に渡すだけですので、JavaScript に関する知識は無くても問題にはなりません。ですが、今後のために少し学習しておくとよいかと思います。[driver.execute_script](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) は、APIとしては JavaScript コードを渡すだけ(引数を渡すことができますが)なので、勉強するほどのこともないでしょう。

Comment: 先程気が付いたのですが、`execute_script()` を使うまでもなく、単にリンクをクリックするだけで問題ありませんでした。

Comment: どうもありがとうございます。結局、今回の件では JavaScriptの知識は不要ということですね。ところで、胴元からチャットに移動してくれと言ってきています。チャットに移動してもいいですか？

Comment: 何度もすみません。`execute_script()` を使った場合のリストを再度表示してくださいませんか？後学のために参考にしたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: どちらか分からなかったので2通り貼ってみました。

Comment: 何度も対応してくださり、ありがとうございます。また疑問が出たら質問すると思いますので、よろしくお願いいたします。